# How to assign dates on x-axis to the barplot in R?

Tags: r, date, bar-chart, axis, axis-labels

I have multiple dates data set that I would like to plot using barplot functions in R. The data is for two different periods so I want to have its respective dates on the x-axis for ease of comparison. Here is my code so far. A_Date is for dataset in A while B_Date is for dataset contain in B.

```
A= runif(24, min = 25, max = 45)
B=runif(24, min = 35, max = 100)
DF=rbind(A,B)

A_Date= as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("1987-01-01"), to= as.Date("1988-12-31"),by="months"))
names(A_Date)= "Dates"
A_Date$year=as.numeric(format(A_Date$Dates, "%Y"))
A_Date$month=as.numeric(format(A_Date$Dates, "%m"))
A_Date=A_Date[,-1]
A_Date = as.character(paste(month.abb[A_Date$month], A_Date$year, sep = "_" ))

B_Date= as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), to= as.Date("2011-12-31"),by="months"))
names(B_Date)= "Dates"
B_Date$year=as.numeric(format(B_Date$Dates, "%Y"))
B_Date$month=as.numeric(format(B_Date$Dates, "%m"))
B_Date=B_Date[,-1]
B_Date = as.character(paste(month.abb[B_Date$month], B_Date$year, sep = "_" ))

barplot(DF, beside = T, col = c("red","darkblue"), legend.text =c("1987-88", "2010-11"), args.legend =list(x="topleft", cex = 1.2, bty="n", x.intersp=0.2),
        ylab = "Precipitation (mm)", cex.axis = 1.2, cex.lab=1.5)
```

Also, I would like to have x-axis line (just like the line on y-axis. 
Thank you

Comment: Are you wanting an answer in base R or can it be ggplot2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`barplot` also throws a coordinate matrix, which we may catch by assignment, here by `b <-`. Now we can make an `axis` with ticks at the right places. To avoid that the plot becomes too crowded, we could unify the redundant month information and just split the different years in `mtext`lines. I've used here built-in `month.abb`s.

```
b <- barplot(DF, beside=T, col=c("red","darkblue"), 
             legend.text=c("1987-88", "2010-11"), 
             args.legend=list(x="topleft", cex=1.2, bty="n", x.intersp=0.2),
             ylab="Precipitation (mm)", cex.axis=1.2, cex.lab=1.5, ylim=c(0, 130))
axis(1, at=b[1, ], labels=FALSE)
axis(1, at=b[2, ], labels=FALSE)
mtext(rep(c(1987, 1988), each=12), 1, 1, at=b[1, ], cex=.8, las=2)
mtext(rep(c(2010, 2011), each=12), 1, 1, at=b[2, ], cex=.8, las=2)
mtext(rep(month.abb, 2), 1, 3, at=colMeans(b), las=2)
```

### Result

[image]

If you'd also like to close the gap between `y` and `x` axis, you could add this line:

```
abline(h=0, cex=1.3)
```

Comment: Exactly as I wanted- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it's going to be hard to fit all 4 dates into one spot on the axis. Here is the best I could come up with. I also rearranged your data so it fits all in one dataframe and used ggplot2.

```r
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- tibble(precip = runif(48, c(25, 25), c(45,100)),
                 dates = c(seq(as.Date("1987-01-01"), as.Date("1988-12-31"), by = "months"),
                           seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2011-12-31"), by = "months")),
                 group = ifelse(lubridate::year(dates) %in% c(1987,1988), "1987-88", "2010-11"), 
                 month = lubridate::month(dates)) 

ggplot(new_df, aes(x = month, y = precip, fill = group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge()) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels = paste0(1:12, "/1987 - 1988", "\n", 1:12, "/2010 - 2011"), 
                       breaks = 1:12) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "navy")) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
          axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

Comment: This is good but probably missing 2010-2011 data set. I have four years: 1987-88 and 2010-2011 data while the graph shows data for two years only. Thanks for responding- there are good functions to work with.